# iOS Autolayout: How to resize a view's height and update other view's frame related to it?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am new to Auto Layout in iOS. My application has a `Textview` and a Button below the `textview`. The application need to update the textview's height and so the button always appear at the bottom of the `textview`. The views have enable Auto Layout. In my code, I do:

1.Change the frame of the green textview

```
self.testView.frame = FRAME(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 10);
```

2.Call the view to update

```
   [self.view invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
```

The problem is that the `textview` updates its height but it overlaps the button below it. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it with code if `you are >= iOS 6`. Purely use autolayout. You need to set vertical spacing between textview and button.

[image]

This will show a constant space between your textview and button like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
In your case:

`UIButton`'s `y` axis = `UITextView`'s height + `UIButton`'s existing `y` + `10`

Comment: Thanks @Vaibhav Saran. I did so but my textview's height is dynamic, it increases by 10 for some action. The problem is when textview's height increases, textview will overlap the button below. Any idea?

Comment: oh! I thought your `TextView` height decreases on increases on device rotation. `AutoLAyout` is made to simplify issues related to device rotation and universal apps. In your case you should disable `autolayout` then do it through code only. When `UITextView` increases height then increase `y` of your `UIButton` by `10`.
See my update on my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @Vaibhav. Hope Apple will update more features to Auto Layout :).